# Fill specific columns in datagridview from MySQL data VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have created a Datagridview with 4 Columns, EJ:

```
ID, Name, Quantity, other
```

But i want to fill these 3 Columns from MySQL EJ:

```
item_id, item_name, item_quantity
```

I tryed this code:

```
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("server=10.10.2.1;userid=root;password=gf-159753;database=quick_admon")
        cn.Open()

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from qa_items", cn)
        ' DataTable  
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        ' llenar el DataTable  
        da.Fill(dt)

        ' enlazar el DataTable al BindingSource  
        list_items.DataSource = dt

        With list_items 
            .MultiSelect = False 
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

            .DataSource = list_items.DataSource
        End With

    End Using
```

but this creates new columns and does not write to the existing, took a while looking for a solution but only find methods like this.

Comment: Do you really want the server IP, userid, and password to be shown to every viewer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You failed to `bind` the columns from your query into your datagrid view columns. To do this,

> 1.) **Right Click** DataGridView. 
>   2.) A Popup Menu appears and **Click Edit Columns** 
>   3.) Bind each columns (*ID*, *Name*, *Quantity*, *other*) by typing the field name (item_id, item_name, item_quantity) respectively from
>   your query in the **DataPropertyName** property (*so that it will not
>   create another column like you did*).

And you're done!

**UPDATE**

Setting **DataPropertyName** Propgramatically

```
list_items.Columns("ID").DataPropertyName = "item_id"
```

or Assuming that ID is your first column:

```
list_items.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "item_id"
```