# how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to bind my **DataTable** to my **DataGridView**.
i do this:

```
        DTable = new DataTable();
        SBind = new BindingSource();
        //ServersTable - DataGridView
        for (int i = 0; i < ServersTable.ColumnCount; ++i)
        {
            DTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(ServersTable.Columns[i].Name));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Apps.Count; ++i)
        {
            DataRow r = DTable.NewRow();
            r.BeginEdit();
            foreach (DataColumn c in DTable.Columns)
            {
                r[c.ColumnName] = //writing values
            }
            r.EndEdit();
            DTable.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        SBind.DataSource = DTable;
        ServersTable.DataSource = SBind;
```

But all i got is **DataTable** *ADDS NEW* columns to my **DataGridView**.
I don't need this, i just need to write under existing columns.

Comment: You don't have any `DataSet`, you just have a `BindingSource` and a `DataTable`. your `BindingSource` is blank.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ServersTable.Columns.Clear();
    ServersTable.DataSource = SBind;
```

If you don't want to clear all the existing columns, you have to set `DataPropertyName` for each existing column like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ServersTable.ColumnCount; ++i) {
  DTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(ServersTable.Columns[i].Name));
  ServersTable.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = ServersTable.Columns[i].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Even better:

```
DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
SBind.DataSource = DTable;
DataGridView ServersTable = new DataGridView();

ServersTable.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
ServersTable.DataSource = DTable;

ServersTable.DataSource = SBind;
ServersTable.Refresh();
```

You're telling the bindable source that it's bound to the DataTable, in-turn you need to tell your DataGridView not to auto-generate columns, so it will only pull the data in for the columns you've manually input into the control... lastly refresh the control to update the databind.

Comment: it's looks like you're right, but now it just adds new empty rows without any cells filled. looks like datagridview don't know which columns needs to fill.

Comment: You'll have to express the SBind.DataMember, usually the ID of the row.  And you'll need to set the DataPropertyName for each of the columns, ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154130/fill-specific-columns-in-datagridview-from-mysql-data-vb-net

Comment: Yes, on a DataGridView you have to set DataPropertyName. After that, this solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

On the DataGridView, set the DataPropertyName of the columns to your column names of your DataTable.

Answer (score 3):

// I built my datatable first, and populated it, columns, rows and all.
//Then, once the datatable is functional, do the following to bind it to the DGV.  NOTE: the DGV's AutoGenerateColumns property must be 'true' for this example, or the "assigning" of column names from datatable to dgv will not work. I also "added" my datatable to a dataset previously, but I don't think that is necessary.

```
 BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
 SBind.DataSource = dtSourceData;

 ADGView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;  //must be "true" here
 ADGView1.Columns.Clear();
 ADGView1.DataSource = SBind;

 //set DGV's column names and headings from the Datatable properties
 for (int i = 0; i < ADGView1.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
       ADGView1.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = dtSourceData.Columns[i].ColumnName;
       ADGView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = dtSourceData.Columns[i].Caption;
 }
 ADGView1.Enabled = true;
 ADGView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: This works for me only if I comment out the "Columns.Clear()" line.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable StudentDataTable = new DataTable("Student");

        //perform this on the Load Event of the form
        private void AddColumns() 
        {
            StudentDataTable.Columns.Add("First_Int_Column", typeof(int));
            StudentDataTable.Columns.Add("Second_String_Column", typeof(String));

            this.dataGridViewDisplay.DataSource = StudentDataTable;
        }
    }

    //Save_Button_Event to save the form field to the table which is then bind to the TableGridView
    private void SaveForm()
        {
            StudentDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { textBoxFirst.Text, textBoxSecond.Text});

            dataGridViewDisplay.DataSource = StudentDataTable;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for example we want to set a DataTable 'Users' to DataGridView by followig 2 steps :
step 1 - get all Users by :

```
public DataTable  getAllUsers()
    {
        OracleConnection Connection = new OracleConnection(stringConnection);
        Connection.ConnectionString = stringConnection;
        Connection.Open();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("semect * from Users");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = Connection;

        using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
        {
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }

        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

step  2- set the return result to DataGridView :

```
public void setTableToDgv(DataGridView DGV, DataTable table)
    {
        DGV.DataSource = table;
    }
```

using example:

```
    setTableToDgv(dgv_client,getAllUsers());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in Hashtable)
{
    datagridviewTZ.Rows.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
}
```