# Base64 String from Xml to DataGridViewColumn as Image Column

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

Bind `DataSet` to `DataGridView.DataSource` works fine. by this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlFilePath);

dataGrid.DataSource = ds;
dataGrid.DataMember = "Teacher";
```

**XML**

```
<Teachers>
<Teacher>
    <FullName>AAAAAA</FullName>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    .
    .
    .
    . More than 15 Columns
    .
    <Photo> --- Base64 string--- </Photo>
</Teacher>
<Teacher>
.
.
.
</Teacher>
</Teachers>
```

But How to Convert the Element's Base64 String to Image Column in `DataGridView`. The `Photo` Column Shows as is. (BASE64 string).

**--Later--**

I tried this.

```
private void dg_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Photo" && !dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value + ""))
        {
            e.Value = Base64ToImage(e.Value + "");
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is like this...

[image: DataGrid Output]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your datagrids' autogeneratecolumns property to false. Then in the Columns property of the Datagrid, generate the columns yourself, in design view. Make sure to set the Column that holds the Image to DataGridViewImageColumn.

Dont forget to set the DataPropertyName on your columns as you are creating them in design view. This will allow the DataGridView to know what it's supposed to load, from the datasource.

That should work, in conjunction with what you have already done above.

Check out this link [how to bind datatable to datagridview in c sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp) for more information.