# How to Bind Datatable with datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I know to bind datagridview to datatable

```
                  dgv.DataSource = table2;
```

But i want to bind in a reverse manner 
something like this

```
                  Datatable table2 = dgv.DataSource;
```

because I am Updating my datagridview for every second and when i close my application I want to store the datagridview in the datatable.I need to do some calculations can any one please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `dgv.DataSource` already contains `DataTable`, you can try to type-cast `dgv.DataSource` to `DataTable` :

```
Datatable table2 = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

[how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

Possible duplicate of the above question.

Hope this helps.

Have a nice day! 
:D