# How to change datagridview colors based on value contained within cells

Tags: c#

Hi all I would like to change cell index based on certain value like shown below ,I have seen many articles in here, but in ASP.NET this is a windows app how can I archive this thanks with a windows desktop app.**Please Note** the column that I want indexes changed is created dynamically.Thanks
**Dynamic column code creation**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adap.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
       table.Columns.Add("RESULTS").Expression = "Iif(((ActualWeight >= (.96 * TargetWeight)) And (ActualWeight <= (1.04 * TargetWeight))),'GOOD''BAD'))

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "BAD")
                    row.Cells[7].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                //row.Cells["RESULTS"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

}
```

Comment: So do you want to change it on click or based on the value?

Comment: Yes sir, like if cell[4]=='bad' ,color=='RED'

Comment: @Sheldon what is this table? What is the name of the DataGridView?

Comment: name is dataGridView1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are adding a new column to the datatable `table`, you need to bind the table to the datagridview (refer this : [how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)) and then try to change the color.

Try this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red; //change the color to what you need
}
```

**UPDATE :** To iterate through the DataGridView and check for cell contents in a specific column, you need something like

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "BAD")
        row.Cells[7].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        //row.Cells["RESULTS"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

You need to place this piece of code inside an event that is triggered or function that is called after the DataGridView is populated with data.

[image]

Comment: @ Saagar your idea leads to the right direction but how do I apply say if in cells[7] has a value 'BAD' I want to be red and so on....

Comment: Object does not contain defn for "Cells"

Comment: You are right , after using updated code ==>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: try this `row.Cells[7].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;`

Comment: Thanks @ Sagaar yelling  at"DefaultCellStyle"

Comment: No, I am trying to chage it around like this because since the column that has Cells[7] is called RESULTS maybe thats why, so I tried this but it yelled =>   if((string )row.Cells[7]["RESULTS"] == "BAD")
                        row.Cells[7].Value = Color.Red;

Comment: @Sheldon, that wont work. The code I pasted above is working perfect for me... can you please paste the whole code?

Comment: Yea I have your code under my event button, but no results keep yelling about obj reference type

Comment: which event? `CellContentClick`? put that under `Form1_Load` after the GridView is loaded with data...

Comment: No , under a buttonclick even that does some computation and has the results as BAD, GOOD AND SO ON, And I have placed ur code after computation has taken place

Comment: I do that because I perform some calculations on the fly and these are done dynamically and put your code after that is that an issue then?

Comment: Yes I am adding it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code demonstrating the desired result

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
                al.Add("open"); al.Add("close"); al.Add("other"); al.Add("open"); al.Add("other"); al.Add("close"); al.Add("open");
                this.GridView1.DataSource = al;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

            protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "open")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "close")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```