# When running my application, SqlAdapter returns no data, when I'm running a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, datagridview

It looks like it connects fine and does everything except returning data or displaying it on the datagridview. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with this. It runs fine on the local machine if I run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

It doesn't seem to run correctly here though, its just a button that I'm clicking but nothing comes back to me.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

SqlCommand StoredProcedureCommand = new SqlCommand("storedprocedure", conn);
StoredProcedureCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter myParam1 = StoredProcedureCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
myParam1.Value = "Arg";

SqlParameter myParam2 = StoredProcedureCommand.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
myParam2.Value = "Gra";

try
{
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Success");
}
catch (Exception conerr)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Failed");
}

try
{
    StoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Running stored procedure succeeded");
}
catch (Exception proerr)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Running stored procedure failed");
}

try
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(StoredProcedureCommand))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        adap.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        MessageBox.Show("Data returned fine" + " This many rows were returned" + rowCount.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception erradapt)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving data to grid" +  erradapt.ToString());
}

try
{  
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Closing database connection");
}
catch (Exception errclose)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error closing database connection");
}
```

Comment: From  StoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); it is inferred that it is used to perform catalog operations, that means This method is to be used to perform DML, later you are trying to use the same stored proc to return data and fill the data grid which will not return anything as only DML operation is performed not select operation.May be you want to call diffrent procedure.

Comment: hmm okay I see you are right i'm not inserting or updating anything it is pretty much just a select statement DDL query. I also tried StoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteReader(); but didn't have any success with that either.

Comment: if by select statement DDL query you mean to create table using select statement then also it is not going to return anything. Select statement in stored procedure should  return rows then only it can be filled in grid. You can try executing the stored proc directly in DB and see if it returns any rows.It will be more helpful if you can provide select statement of stored proc with the question.

Comment: this is a stored procedure already on the server, it runs fine locally but for some reason it just doesn't return any data back to me. If I run this procedure and those parameters on the local server it will give me 18 rows back. this is a windows form that is not giving me back data, its running the procedure over the internet. I can grab the procedure in a few. Thanks for helping by the way! I appreciate it

Comment: Have you tried taking out the StoredProcedureCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); line? Maybe the Fill operation does not execute the command again since you already did that beforehand.

Comment: Yeah i have tried with out the .ExecuteNonQuery(); but still returns nothing not entirely sure why not. I have gone through a handful of forums and they all look very similar to mine I just can't see why it doesn't work. It doesn't error out it goes through everything fine, i put in a few try catches to see if i caught an exception but nope goes through it all fine but doesn't populate anything on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that your rowCount variable will always be 0 because it was assigned to before dt was filled. If you were using the rowCount for any kind of loop, the loop would just exit immediately. And your message will always say "This many rows came back 0".

Btw, I have used a similar piece of code in my application and it does work.

Comment: Okay but would that explain the datagridview1 not being populated as well? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could try this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp
I can see the DataSource being populated in my test code. It s important that your data table got populated after store procedure executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help the problem was the connection string after going back to the stored procedure I noticed it

Thanks all for the help!!