# add 3 fields(editable)which user can update del and save all data in Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i need help in displaying folder contents in gridview later add 3 fields (editable) which user can update delete and save all this data in database.

Here is my code for displaying folder contents:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("File Name");
table.Columns.Add("Sequence");
table.Columns.Add("Delay");

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
    table.Rows.Add(file.Name);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem briefly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: display folder contents which will not be constant and after displaying 3 fields sequence, format,delay must be added to the gridview which user will  update/delete. i am able to display folder contents but now how to connect that data with database? @nayan

Comment: @NazneenSayed You should [edit] your question when you comment explaning the problem is longer than the non-code part of it...

Answer (score 0):

It must be somethink like that:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("File Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Sequence");

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
        DataRow r = table.NewRow();
        r["File Name"] = file.Name;
        r["Sequence"] = "OtherString";
        table.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: DataRow r = table.AddNewRow();

doesnot accept that way .i am using visual studio 2015 in c# language

Comment: also like we have  r["File Name"] = file.Name; means file.name is assinging to the field filename likewise i need for delay and sequence which i cant find any.