# Why does not work binding DataSource with DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have code, that fill Datagridview from DataTable:

```
public void dataGridClientsLoad()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = serviceSqlite.select(new Pacients());

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            //dataGridView2.Update();

            //dataGridView2.Refresh();

            label1.Text = "Все" + updateCountRows();

        }
```

In `dt` object I have get filled rows and columns(see pic.1, pic.2).

But as result, I have empty DataGridView after calling `dataGridClientsLoad()`, why?
[image: pic.1]

[image: pic.2]

**ServiceSqlite** is:

```
class SqliteService : ArraySelect
    {
        public SQLiteDatabase driver;

        public SqliteService() {

            SqliteConnection(new SQLiteDatabase());
        }

        public void SqliteConnection(SQLiteDatabase driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
        }

        public DataTable select(ISqlite select)
        {

            return select.select(driver);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView();`?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp help?

Comment: dt does not have mrthod `DefaultView()`

Comment: I tried, not working

Comment: It returns DataTable, see pics in question

Comment: You mean what type retuns `serviceSqlite.select`?

Comment: What is the type of `serviceSqlite`. Please include the code where `serviceSqlite` is declared so we can see its `Type`. Also please include the source code from its `select` function.

Comment: public DataTable select(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
       return db.GetDataTable("sql");}

Comment: Is AutoGenerateColumns true?

Comment: `DataGridView` need to know what columns to show. If `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true` then `DataGridView` will generate columns automatically. If it is `false`, then you should have predefined columns created from code or from designer with properly defined `DataPropertyName` for every column. `DataPropertyName` should refer to column name in `DataTable`. Did you changed names of columns? - Other tip check if you "reset" datasource somewehre else in the code. With information you provided your code should work

Comment: in Windows application binding is Simple DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("MyCol", typeof(string));

            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            drow["MyCol"] = "MyData";
            dt.Rows.Add(drow);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: So, I should set `AutoGenerateColumns` as true?

Comment: if you only want to bind the data in datatable then no need to set AutoGenerateColumns property,
simply clear the rows and column by dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); and bind the datasource with datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DataBind() after setting data source to grid view-

> dataGridView1.DataBind();

Binds the data source to the GridView control. This method cannot be inherited.

Use the DataBind() method to bind data from a data source to the GridView control. This method resolves all data-binding expressions in the active template of the control.refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void dataGridClientsLoad()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = serviceSqlite.select(new Pacients());

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataBind();//This require to bind data table.  

                label1.Text = "Все" + updateCountRows();

            }
```

Comment: Does not contain property dataGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Is it a web application or windows?

Comment: it is Windows application

Comment: Bind is not available for windows.

Comment: Some tim ago it worked, May be cache? Others solutions?

Comment: _Bind is not available for windows_ `DataGrid` and `DataGridView` are different controls.

Comment: Answer is not useful