# How to read a text file and add the data to a data grid view that has a binding Source

Tags: c#, winforms

Im having difficulties loading from a text file and having that info placed into a data grid view that is data bound using a binding source.

```
private void OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
    var result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)MoviesDataGridView.DataSource;
    DataRow dtRow = (DataRow)MoviesDataGridView.DataSource;

    if (result != DialogResult.OK)
        return;
    try
    {
        using (myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile())
        {
            string newline;
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(myStream);
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] lines = newline.Split('\t');
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    dtRow[i] = lines[i];
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);
            }

            file.Close();
            MoviesDataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk.  Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Want it to open and then load into the `dataGridView` however i get this exception error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.'

Comment: How are you binding the datatable to the GridView in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)MoviesDataGridView.DataSource;
DataRow dtRow = (DataRow)MoviesDataGridView.DataSource;
```

With

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
```

Add columns to the table like this:

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.ColumnName = "id";
table.Columns.Add(column);
```

And create the new row in the while loop with:

```
DataRow dtRow = dataTable.NewRow();
```

Comment: That has fixed the error, now it is saying cannot find column 0. Does this mean I need to add all my columns before loading the file?

Comment: In this case, you had a table without columns. You have to create them in the DataTable.

Comment: Right. Would it be easier to save the columns in the text file then load that way. Or regardless will I have to create the columns?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with "save in the text file", but have to create the column prior to adding rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the code below

```
BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
SBind.DataSource = dataTable;
MoviesDataGridView.Columns.Clear();
MoviesDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;
```

Referenced from:
[how to bind datatable to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)